# Mandrill forward to a friend

Tags: mandrill

How do I forward a page to a Friend in Mandrill API?

I have generated the newsletter html format to send mail through Mandrill and it is properly sent. But I want to forward a friend to in my newsletter html file.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mandrill doesn't offer that feature.  You can read more [here](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/28524968-Can-I-use-MailChimp-merge-tags-in-Mandrill-emails-)

From their documentation:

> The MailChimp *|FORWARD|* merge tag generates a link to an online form
>   where recipients can share your email with others. Since Mandrill
>   emails are generated and tracked individually, a web version isn't
>   provided automatically. To mimic the Forward to a Friend option in
>   Mandrill, you could create your own online version of the email, host
>   it on your website, and then give your recipients a way to share that
>   online version with friends (through a direct link or an online form).
>   Then you could track when people fill out the form or when they click
>   the link for the shared email.